# Working with multiple github accounts with SSH fails

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, account

I have a personal and a work accounts on github. I have SSH keys for both and this `config` file in the `~/.ssh`

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work-rsa-key
```

When I work with the personal account all is fine but when I try to pull/push to the work account I get

```
$ git pull
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Of course I verified the address is correct.

When I do `ssh -T git@github.com` I get `Hi ilya! ...` which is the personal user name.

This is the `config` for the work account:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[branch "dev"]
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github-work:work/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/dev
[branch "unify"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/unify
[user]
    name = ilya-work
    email = ilya@work.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you done `ssh-add ~/.ssh/work-rsa-key` ?

Verifiy that all your keys are listed by doing `ssh-add -l`.

Then, you can do the following:

```
git config user.name "ilya-work"
git config user.email "ilya@work.com"
```

Now, `git pull` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your SSH config section:

```
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

For example:

```
Host github-work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work-rsa-key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Alternatively, you might want to add your private key identitiy to the authentication agent, by running

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/work-rsa-key
```

When executing `git pull`, it will try every identities found in your authentication agent. That's why this method is not (much) recommended.